# How does Asp.net 4.5.x MVC work with Angular 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm learning to use Angular 2 with asp.net. I've got it to work, but I don't understand how it's working.

My understanding is that with MVC5, when you request a page from an action method of a controller, it will look inside the 'Views' folder for a html file with the same name as the action method and return it.

However, following this guide for setting up angular 2 in Visual Studio: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

I now have an 'app' folder that's sibling to the 'Views' folder. and an index.html that's in the root of the project folder. So how is it when I launch the app, the index.html from the project root is returned, and not the 'index.html' from the 'Views'->'Home' folder?

Also, this current setup seems a bit messy. Is there a way for me to move all the angular related stuff into one folder called 'client' for example?

Comment: Requests for static resources like HTML files by default doesn't even go through ASP.NET routing server. Thus the default file configured in IIS or web.config is served from the folder. And yes, you are free to move your files around - try it and see what happens.

Comment: @mason I see, then I'm even more confused. I've seen a few tutorials around the web where they use gulp to compile the scripts and somehow integrate angular into the cshtml inside the 'Views' folder. But if we can put angular's index.html anywhere, what's the benefit of using gulp?

Comment: Gulp is a build system, a task runner. CSHTML is a server side technology for generating HTML. Angular is a client side technology. So your question is all over the place. I suggest you just start with some simple tutorials before you start trying to combine multiple technologies.

Comment: @mason I know CSHTML. I can do normal ASP.NET MVC fine. I've built a few simple apps with Angular and node. I've finished the official Angular 2 tutorial, and the Angular Intro course on MVA. I know the purpose of Gulp, though I've never used it. I think my question's pretty straight forward. How do I put Angular 2 and MVC together? Why do you say I can put the index.html anywhere. Why are other people doing it another way. And in both cases, the index.html that's suppose to be Angular's starting point is not sitting inside the Views folder, which is what I'm use to. Why is that?

Comment: How you put them together is really up to you. You can put it anywhere because you can put it anywhere. Other people do it other ways because that's how they choose to do it. Index.html can be put anywhere that IIS will serve static files out of. A lot of these questions you're asking are simply opinion based on how you can choose to structure your project. You can easily experiment and see what works best for your style and your app.

Comment: @mason So I've tried putting all the angular things inside a folder called client at the root of the project. The index.html will only be served if the url is /client/index.html. I can navigate to other routes eg /profile using the built in router in angular. But If I type /profile into the url, I get a 404. I think I understand what you mean. If it's a static file, it can be placed anywhere. and if I type in the correct url, i'll get to it. But I don't want angular to be treated as a static file. I want it to be able to handle all the routing. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Synia I think you are mixing things up. ASP MVC is a server side, and angular is client side. You can use any client side frameworks, and you don't have to use any template. My suggestion for you is first read about IIS and understand how it really serves files and URL, understand HTTP handlers really well, and then read about MVC routing and understand it really well. After that you should be clear on your questions.